# Groovy complaining about illegal character range in regex

Tags: regex, groovy

Groovy 2.4 here. I am trying to build a regex that will filter out all the following characters:

```
`,./;[]-&<>?:"()|
```

Here's my best attempt:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    // `,./;[]-&<>?:"()|
    String regex = "`,./;[]-&<>?:\"()|"
    String test = "ooekrofkrofor ` oxkeoe , wdkeodeko / kodek ] woekoedk \" swjiej ' wsjwdjeiji :"
    println test.replaceAll(regex, "")
}
```

However this produces a compile error on the `regex` string definition, complaining:

> illegal character range (to < from)

Not sure if this is a Java or Groovy thing, but I can't figure out how to define the `regex` properly so that it quiets the error and correctly strips these "illegal characters" out of my string. Any ideas?

Comment: do you need to escape some more (other than ")? [\^$.|?*+() are special characters for regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you want to remove all the characters listed in your `regex` variable. The problem is that you declared a *sequence* while you need a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (enclose the characters with `[]`).

See [Groovy demo](http://ideone.com/pNZAfd):

```
String regex = "[`,./;\\[\\]&<>?:\"()|-]+"
                ^     ^^^^^^          ^ ^  
String test = "ooekrofkrofor ` oxkeoe , wdkeodeko / kodek ] woekoedk \" swjiej ' wsjwdjeiji :"
println test.replaceAll(regex, "")
```

Output: `ooekrofkrofor  oxkeoe  wdkeodeko  kodek  woekoedk  swjiej ' wsjwdjeiji`

The pattern now contains a character class matching any of the characters defined inside it - `` [`,./;\[\]&<>?:\"()|-] `` - *one or more times* due to the `+` quantifier. Note that inside the character class, `]` and `[` must always be escaped, and the `-` can be left unescaped when placed at the start/end of the character class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape a few special characters in your pattern:

```
 String regex = "[`,./;\\[]\\-&<>?:\"\\(\\)|]+"
```

Note using double `\\` to turn them into a single `\` in the string, so when the pattern is parsed, the next character is escaped.